# Some Regex stuff

Tags: python, regex

I'm just starting to figure out regex and would love some help trying to understand it. I've been using [this](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to help me get started, but am still having some trouble figuring it out.

What I am trying to do is take this text:

```
<td>8.54/10 over 190 reviews</td>
```

And pull out the "8.54", so basically anything in between the first ">" and the "/"

Using my noob skills, I came up with this: [0-9].[0-9][0-9], which WILL match that 8.54, and will work for everything BUT 10.00, which I do need to account for.

Can anyone help me refine my expression to apply to that last case as well?

Comment: If you're really looking for 'basically anything in between the first ">" and the "/"', then you should use: `re.search('\>(.*?)/', text).group(1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use quantifiers.

You want one or more digits, followed by a dot, followed by one or more digits. A digit can also be written `\d`, and the "one or more" quantifier is `+`.

The dot needs to be escaped as it is a regex metacharacter which means "any character". Your regex therefore should be:

```
\d+\.\d+
```

Now, beware that a quantifier applies to atoms only. Character classes (`[...]`), complemented character classes (`[^...]`) and special character classes (`\d`, `\w`...) are atoms, however if you want to apply a quantifier to more than a simple atom, you'll need to *group* these atoms using the grouping operator, `()`. Ie, `(ab)+` will look for one or more of `ab`.

Comment: No problem. Google for "mastering regular expressions" and buy the book, it is a great investment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe answered my own question. Found this:

[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]*)

It seems to work, does anyone have any changes to this?

Comment: It won't work, since you use the `*` quantifier, which means "zero or more", so this would match, for instance, `12.`. Also, I think you missed a final `?` after that, right? Otherwise the non capturing group (`(?:...)`) doesn't really make sense. And also see my answer about the dot.

Comment: This will work, but it will also accept a string without digits after the dot at all, which may be or not be what you want. Also, `[0-9]` can be written more compactly as `\d`.

Answer (score 0):

`\d` is often used instead of `[0-9]` (mnemonically, “***d**igit*”) and it's necessary to remember that sometimes fractional numbers are written without any digits before the decimal point. Thus:

```
(?<=>)(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?=/)
```

OK, that's a bit of a complex RE. Here's how it breaks down (in extended form).

```
(?<= > )          # With a “>” before (but not matched)…
(?:               # … match either this
   \d+            #   at least one digit, followed by…
   (?:            #   …match
      \. \d*      #     a dot followed by any number of digits
   ) ?            #   optionally
|                 # … or this
   \. \d+         #   a dot followed by at least one digit
)                 #
(?= / )           # … and with a “/” afterwards (but not matched)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
\>(.*?)/

# (.*?) is a "non-greedy" group which maches as few characters as possible
```

Then access the actual value using

```
m.group(1)
```

where m is the match object returned by re.search or re.finditer

If you want to access the value directly (re.findall), use

```
(?>=\>)(.*?)(?=/)
```